# Firebase deploy broken after migrating to new console-- "Error: Authentication required."

Tags: node.js, deployment, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

After migrating my app to the new Firebase console (console.firebase.google.com), I can no longer deploy static assets using the Firebase CLI "firebase deploy".  I receive the message "Error: Authentication required."

At first, I had updated to the latest CLI but found I couldn't use it to deploy without updating Firebase in my Angular app; I'm not ready to do this until AngularFire has been updated though.  So I downgraded to the older CLI but found I still couldn't deploy.

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling Firebase CLI, Firebase, NodeJS (v4 & 6), logging in and logging out of Firebase multiple times-- nothing has helped.

I'm currently using:

- Firebase CLI: 2.15.1
- Node: 4.4.4
- NPM: 2.15.1

I've also tried using "firebase prefs:token", copying the token, and deploying with the token via "firebase deploy --token ".  Still no luck. Authentication required.

Hoping for some guidance on the issue to unblock deployment.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry you're running into issues. You should be using the `firebase-tools` node module. The latest version is 3.0.0. This is required to use projects that have been migrated to the new console.

Try running:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
# just to be sure; let's make sure you have a token against the right scopes
firebase logout; firebase login
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip-- figured it out!  I was running firebase-tools (aka the Firebase CLI) 2.15.1 after finding that 3.0.0 didn't work, but I gave it another try.  

The issue was a bit more complicated: "firebase use default" wouldn't work (error: "please verify project exists and you have access."--of course I do).  Running "firebase list", I found that my project id was different from the project name.  I gather the name was taken on Google Cloud so a random id was generated, but there was no indication this happened.  After running "firebase use <project id>", "firebase deploy" worked!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I work on the team at Firebase which builds the CLI and would love to fix what confused you. Do you recall what you originally did get the "default" alias for your project? I assume you typed `firebase use --add default MyProjectNameNotMyProjectId` ?